# HTML table cell alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile and I would like to create a listview which should look like

[image]

It looks very simple to achieve and I have got almost everything except the right-alignment of the column on the right.
Note that every three cells on the right-column are merged.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Update:
Here is my code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist"><li><table><tr><td><label class="label1">EUR</label></td><td rowspan="3"><label class="price">1.3245</label></td></tr><tr><td><label class="label2">vs</label></td></tr><tr><td><label class="label3">USD</label></td></tr></table></li><li><table><tr><td><label class="label1">EUR</label></td><td rowspan="3"><label class="price">0.89</label></td></tr><tr><td><label class="label2">vs</label></td></tr><tr><td><label class="label3">GBP</label></td></tr></table></li></ul>
```

Comment: What code are you using to get your results? Knowing that will enable people to help.

Comment: There is any css rule to set de right column's width?

Comment: In addition, if you still want the shadow you can add this css rule to your table:   box-shadow: 2px 2px;

Comment: Thanks for the shadow tip. And my css for the right column does not set width. Here it is `.price{ font-size: 30px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling for a while I figured out what the problem was. In my code I'm creating several tables. (One table for each `<li>`.) So when I right-align the text in the right-column, it is right-aligned with-in each table. But when all these tables are seen one-below-the-other the text doesn't appear to be right aligned.
The solution is to right align right-columns in all tables and also maintain fixed width in all tables.e.g. `.price{ font-size: 30px; 
width:200px;
text-align: right;
}`

Thanks Joe W and Rafael de Souza for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Well, as you did not post your code, I can do nothing more than it to help you

[View here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGzin)

Code:

```
jQuery('tr').each(function() {
  if (this.cells[1]) {
    this.cells[1].style.textAlign = 'right';
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added my code above. I thought your solution would work. But for some reason it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your css by adding text-align: right it should get you the results you need.

before:

```
.price{ font-size: 30px;}
```

after:

```
.price{ font-size: 30px; text-align: right;}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe W, I tried that. But for some reason it is not working.